# Updating Side Panel when add/remove emails to compose widget

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

As far as I know, Gmail add-on can be showen in two places, one inside the left panel and another one inside the compose message widget. Figured-out that the side panel can be updated only when opening an email. So basically I want to update the side panel when the user add/remove email in the compose widget. Is this possible?

[image]

Manifest

```
"gmail": {
  "contextualTriggers": [{
    "unconditional": {
    },
    "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
  }],
  "composeTrigger": {
    "selectActions": [{
      "text": "Wired2Perform",
      "runFunction": "onGmailMessage"
    }],
    "draftAccess": "METADATA"
  }
}
```

Trigger Function

```
function onGmailMessage(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var emails = extractEmailsFromMessage(event);
  console.log(emails);
  if(emails.length > 0) {
    var w2pData = w2pClient().getUsersList(emails);
    return buildW2pCommunicationCard(w2pData);
  } else {
    // add email for more info
    return createHomeCard();
  }
}
```

console.log(event) is not called when adding/removig emails

Comment: Hi there @DilipTharuka! Just to make it clear, I understand that you want to update the right side panel based on the contents of the compose window. Is that correct? Moreover, did you take a look at [add-on docs when composing a mail](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui)? Finally, please share your current code so we all can take a look at it.

Comment: After reviewing your update I have a new doubt. When you say  «*So basically I want to update the side panel when the user add/remove email*», what do you mean by «*when the user add/remove email*»?

Comment: You can see I have added my email `Dilip Tharuka` in compose window, want to update side panel when I am adding or removing emails in compose window.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is possible to use the Card service to [update the draft contents](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui#inserting_content_into_active_drafts), is that a valid workaround in your scenario? If not please define why you need to update the sidebar based in the draft body so we all can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Read and compose UI are two separate UIs that cannot interact with one another.

**2 standalone UIs**

The documentation is kind of confusing on that point, but there are *two distinct* UIs that you can build - both are self-contained and cannot interact with one another:

- message (read mode)
- compose (draft mode)

The catch with the docs consists in the fact that message UI can *compose drafts* using `Action` instances via [`setComposeAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setComposeAction(Action,ComposedEmailType)). In the callback, you provide for the action you can only create and prefill *the draft*, not interact with the compose UI.

**Compose actions**

> Unfortunately, Gmail Add-ons do not have events that fire on draft edit

The `gmail.composeTrigger` only runs when a user either ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui)):

1. Replies to a message when the Add-on is opened
2. Launches the Add-on from the sidebar when a draft is open

The callback specified in `runFunction` field of a [`SelectAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons#selectaction) of the `selectActions` array is responsible for building the *initial* display of the Add-on. From now on the only way to update the Add-on UI is in the [`UpdateDraftActionResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-action-response) returned by an `Action` callback running when a user interacts with a *widget in the compose UI* (that can have `Action`s assigned to it).